# Reading from RecordSet in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset, ms-access-2010

I'm working on MS ACCESS 2010

I have a table in which employee id's and some other fields are stored as

```
f123 - - -
f543 - - -
f654 - - -
f123 - - -
```

etc.

'when i run

```
strSQL="Select Distinct emp_id from Tbl"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
    idVar = rs!Emp_Id
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The values obtained in recordset are **123, 543 etc.** instead of **f123, f543 etc.**
When i run the query in query design view it works perfectly. Pls help.

Comment: Are you sure that Emp_Id is not formatted in some way to include the 'f'? What data type is Emp_Id?

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere other than this code snippet.  We could help you better if you tell us your goal and how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: Try to declare idVar as string: "Dim idVar as String" before all

Answer (score 3):

Code above doesnt run. Code below runs - msgbox included to test values

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim idVar As String

strSQL = "Select Distinct emp_id from Tbl"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
    idVar = rs!Emp_Id
    MsgBox idVar 'check value
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer. There is nothing wrong with the code above, it is a snippet. I am tempted to vote down, but I'll assume a misunderstanding instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to recreate the problem without any success I'm afraid.

Please see screen dump.  Not sure if this is going to help you though.

Thanks Mark
[image: Screen dump of code running in debug mode]

Comment: Are you user1063226? If so, you need to post the table details, as per my comment to the original post. Furthermore, in StackOverflow, you add to your question by editing, this area is reserved for answers to the question.